# Similarity of two words in GloVe

Tags: python, glove

How to find similarity of two words in Glove? We have `model.similarity(word1, word2)` in Word2vec. Is there a similar way in GloVe? How to save and load trained GloVe model?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html)

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity([[1, 0, -1]], [[-1,-1, 0]])
array([[-0.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

**EDIT**

You can use SciPy package. Python code for cosine similarity:

```
from scipy import spatial

word_1 = [3, 45, 7, 2]
word_2 = [2, 54, 13, 15]
result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(word_1, word_2)
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you please write the syntax?

Comment: Edited in the post :)